# Add more button does not worked any more

Tags: 7, entities, javascript

I added date field with unlimited values,it was working perfectly but suddenly it's stop adding new values.
when click on in just the first time the blue circle appear for second and nothing happen after that, then the button does not work.
sory for my english :)

Comment: Are you using Jquery Update module? There's a bug currently, try setting it back to version 1.5 or disabling it.

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: @Volker i don't use jquery update modeule

Comment: @2pha no java script errors

Comment: Check out this solution: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65328/ajax-ahah-add-more-button-on-unlimited-cardinality-fields-conflicts-with-cus